# Modify my question after successfully answered but still not accepted

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, asking-questions

[This is my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13766756/1297603). 5 min after received a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13766851/1297603), I even upvoted it. But just minutes after upvoting I'm running some tests I realized that my question should have been a little bit different in order to get a somewhat different result.

Should I edit my question, keep the upvote and notify the answerer so he can change the answer? Or do I accept the answer and create a new question? Is just that as result I will end up having 2 almost identical questions.

Comment: Modify and inform is the best way to go about it if you think they are very similar.

Comment: related (probably not a duplicate): [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/165773) "...So you... slog through the ugly code, find the offending line, direct his attention to it and explain why it's wrong and how it needs to be fixed. Later, he leaves a comment saying that yes, that was indeed the problem and your answer helped him fix it *(great!)*.  Oh, but, now there's another problem..."

Comment: @gnat, I don't really got it. I was not having an error or trying to solve a totally/completly different/new question. Just realized that I should have asked a slightly different question as as it was my 2nd question would be then almost a duplicate of the current one. As TinyTimPost already answerered and tvanfosson answered on your question, I modified to avoid duplicates or missunderstandings and clearly have shown what was modified. I always try to find an answer by myself before posting it on SO, sometimes, right after posting, I finally find the solution and I answer myself for others

Comment: @Yaroslav well as long as you don't change too much to make answerer unhappy, I think it would be OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, modify the question - or the next question really becomes a duplicate as answers would cover basically the same ground.

You've done what you need to do, which is:

- Clearly indicate that the scope of the question changed, within the question. This keeps people from wondering if all of the answers you received came from left field
- Notify those that answered that the details have changed

Don't worry about it too much, even when you put a lot of effort into a question, there's always a possibility that you'll think of something else. We do ask that you try and keep *major* scope changes to a minimum, but you obviously understand that.